# How to send a image captured from webcam in PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, opencv

I am capturing an image from `PHP` script from webcam and I want to send it to `python` script so that I can use `OpenCV` feature homography functions on it. How can I send an image using `exec` command in `PHP` and pass that image to `cv2.imread()` function in `python`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not capture the webcam image inside your python script in the first place?

Comment: Or do the rest of the image processing in php.

Comment: Sir, I want to run webcam on a browser as i am trying augmented reality for web.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you can do it all in Python. Python works just as well as a server side script for web as PHP does

Comment: ok sir, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe that if you want to use `cv2.imread` you need to have a file, because one of the parameters is a file name and that is going to make everythins slower and resource consuming.
I think that what you want to use is `cv2.imdecode` (similar to `imread` by in memory), in which case you only need to turn your image into the correct type of stream, a numpy array for example.

I would also consider to process everything on python at once if you want to take in account performance.